# How to list disk usage by directory, excluding certain output

Tags: disk-usage, grep, error-handling, du

I am trying to get a sense of disk usage and I want to exclude the ones I cannot access like this - any suggestions?

```
sudo du -h / --max-depth=1 | grep -v "cannot access"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can redirect the standard error stream to a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#index-process-substitution)

```
du -h / --max-depth=1 2> >(grep -v 'cannot access')
```

This will filter out the `cannot access` error messages, but retain others such as `Permission denied` and so on.